# Expanding set of y axis values in chart, developed by MS-excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have developed a chart from a set of values of excel file, Now what I have to do that I have to expand the y axis values from point 5 to point 8, Can anyone please suggest me that how to do that.

I have chart of following type.

[image]

Reason behind doing so is that, the values between 5 to 8 are not clearly distinguishable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: down voters kindly dare to put your comments.

Comment: Doing what you're asking is a bad idea for column/bar charts.  These chart types should always begin with 0, because you're comparing the total length of the value, not the relative difference between end points of the line. Read more about it at Jon Peltier's excellent blog: http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/bar-chart-value-axis-scale-must-include-zero.  You could consider alternative graphic presentations like small-multiples/lattice charts, or normalizing the values to allow for more discrete comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

#### Make changes to the scales of value axes

1. On a chart sheet or in an embedded chart, **click the value (y) axis** that you want to change.
2. On the **Format** menu, click **Selected Axis**.
3. On the **Scale** tab, change the number at which the value (y) axis starts and ends, **type a different number in the Minimum box**.

Reference: https://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/change-chart-axes-HP003065679.aspx#BMchangevalueaxes

Comment: While the answer is technically correct, remember just because you can change the minimum axis, doesn't mean you should change it.

Comment: ↑ This *but* you should present it as two charts. One that looks like what's the question and another with a min of 5 and max of 8 to show the details. (I second what dav pointed out - gosh - 10 years ago).